# Adding Action in Manage rules in Alfresco

Tags: action, alfresco

I am new to *Alfresco*.
I want to add a new action in *Manage Rules* apart from copy, check in, check out, send mail.

I just want to display this action in UI under *Manage Rules*. 
I tried to add in *share-config-custom.xml* file but the new action in not appearing in new

So which files do I need to change to make the action visible in *Manage rules*?

Answer (score 2):

One of the [tutorials I've written](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series) covers this. It is called [Creating Custom Actions in Alfresco](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html).

But to save you some reading, if you've written your action and configured it in Spring, Share will pick it up automatically and make it available in the rule configuration. If that's not happening you must have missed a step.

Note that the "UI actions" you see listed in the Share config are different from "rule actions" which is what shows up in the rule dialog.